# Having trouble making a sum of 2 set of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement, case

I'm doing a little project and am stuck on this part.

I basically am trying to take the numbers put in by the user for A1 and B1 to make a sum out of it **(3 Compute the Sum of the Elements of A1 and B1).**

This what I got so far and its not working any ideas on how I should tackle this ?

any help is always appreciated thanks!

background information on the program if a better understanding:

The program is meant to take 2 set of numbers from a user (A1,B1) and be put into an array. After the numbers are inputted, the user will be prompt by a menu with options to what they would like to do with the numbers. the option will be sent to one of the 4 cases ( 3 written so far )

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int option; // Int for Menu Option choice
    int i, a, j; //Int FOR A1 
    int n = 10; // Int FOR A1 
    int number[10]; // Int FOR A1

        int sum = 0; // SUM FOR OPTION 3

    int o, s, k; // Int FOR B1
    int m = 10; // Int FOR B1
    int num[10]; //Int for B1 ARRAY

        printf("Enter 10 Numbers for A1\n");  // Numbers for A1
        for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
            scanf("%d", &number[i]);


        printf("Enter 10 Numbers for B1: \n"); //Numbers for B1
        for (o = 1; o < m; ++o)
            scanf("%d", &num[o]);





    //USER PICKS OPTION 
    printf("******************************************************************\n");
    printf("*\tSelect one of the following options                      *\n");
    printf("*\t1   Sort  A1 values in Ascending Order                   *\n");
    printf("*\t2   Sort B1 values into Descending Order                 *\n");
    printf("*\t3   Compute the Sum of the Elements of A1 and B1         *\n");
    printf("*\t4   Subtract the Elements of B1 from the Elements of A1  *\n");
    printf("******************************************************************\n");
    printf("Enter Your Option: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
            {
                if (number[i] > number[j])
                {
                    a = number[i];
                    number[i] = number[j];
                    number[j] = a;
                }
            }

        }
        printf("The numbers arranged in ascending order are given below \n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            printf("%d\n", number[i]);
        break;

    case 2:
        for (o = 0; o < m; ++k)
        {
            for (k = o + 1; k < m; ++k);
            {
                if (num[o] < num[k])
                {
                    s = num[o];
                    num[o] = num[k];
                    num[k] = s;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("The numbers arranged in descending order are given below\n");

        for (o = 0; o < m; ++o)

            printf("%d\n", num[o]);
        break;

      case 3:   // FOR OPTION 3 PART IM LOST ON MAKE A1 AND B1 SUM

        {

            sum = num[o] + number[i];

        }
            printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"This what I got so far and its not working"_ - Define "not working"

Comment: Your loops to input values into both the arrays start from 1 but should start from 0

Comment: `for (k = o + 1; k < m; ++k);` That semicolon at the end makes it a loop without a body

Comment: Reduce your code.

Comment: when i compile it and type in for option 3 it gives me an answer of this Sum = 4196669  but it should equal the sum of A1 and B1 numbers entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you are trying to add the elements in A1 and elements in B1 and storing the addition of sum(A1)+sum (B1) into a variable named sum.

Since the elements are present in array you have to use for loop so change the code in case 3 to :

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  sum=sum+num[i]+number[i];

                }
```

Here print you sum ( after closing for loop)

and if you are trying to add the consecutive elements of arrays you must have a third array that will store the sum of consecutive elements

```
int total[10];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    total[i]=num[i]+number[i];
             }
```

after that use a for loop for to print the elemets

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of 2 matrix must generate a third matrix.
Your code must be something like:

```
int sum[10];
int bigTotal;
...
case 3:
   for(i = 0, bigTotal = 0; i < 10; i++){
      sum[i] = num[i] + number[i];
      bigTotal += sum[i];

      printf("s[%d] = %d\n", i, s[i]);
   }
   printf("Sum of all numbers: %d\n", bigTotal);
   break;
```